# The concept of binary description by Ray Solomonoff

Tags: kolmogorov-complexity

In this article, http://world.std.com/~rjs/rayfeb60.pdf in page 7 of the PDF, Solomonoff gives an a-priori probability for a string which is $pr(S)=2^{-|S|}$.

My question - why are shorter strings considered more probable? Is there some kind of hidden assumption that justifies this?

e.g. that the machine which produces these strings have a constant probability to stop at a any given point (an inherent preference to shorter strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later in page 10 of the pdf he explains that in fact the probabilities are almost 1/2, as there is a very small probability to stop the at each step.

This stems from the following assumption: There is some mechanism that produces these strings, and it does so sequentially, therefore going through shorter strings on its way to longer ones and having a certain probability to stop at each step.

Another explanation that was more satisfying:

These binary strings are in fact prefixes of infinite random sequences. The probability of a prefix to be 1 or 0 is of course 1/2 etc'. The machine that reads these infinite binary strings is a prefix turing machine, which means that if it produces a certain sequence, it does so by reading a prefix of the random string.

Answer (score 1):

It is the consequence of the Occam's razor pinciple and maximum entropy principle, if we interpret Occam's razor as **to minimize the expected codeword length of the model/program**.

Then we can either miximize Shannon entropy with the constraint of finite expected codeword length, or minimize the expected codeword length with the constraint of finite Shannon entropy.

$$\mathop{minimize}\limits_{w_h\vDash\left\{
{\begin{aligned}
&H(w_h)=C_h\\
&\sum\limits_{p:U(p)=h*}w_h^p=1
\end{aligned}}\right.} \sum\limits_{p:U(p)=h*}w_h^p\cdot \ell(p)\qquad\text{or}\qquad\mathop{maximize}\limits_{w_h\vDash\left\{
{\begin{aligned}
&\sum\limits_{p:U(p)=h*}w_h^p\cdot \ell(p)=C_h\\
&\sum\limits_{p:U(p)=h*}w_h^p=1
\end{aligned}}\right.} H(w_h)
$$

The Lagrange multiplier

$$
L_h=\sum\limits_{p:U(p)=h*}w_h^p\cdot \ell(p)-T\left(-\sum\limits_{p:U(p)=h*}w_h^p\log w_h^p-C_h\right)-\lambda\left(\sum\limits_{p:U(p)=h*}w_h^p-1\right)
$$

Then we get

$$\dfrac{\partial L_h}{\partial w_h^p}=0\implies w_h^p=\dfrac{2^{-\frac{\ell(p)}{T}}}{\sum\limits_{p:U(p)=h*}2^{-\frac{\ell(p)}{T}}}
$$

Which is the normalized Solomonoff prior with a 'temperature' parameter $T$.